# Apply function inside bindAttr

Tags: ember.js

I need to apply a function to the property value. I use following code to bind it with an inputbox.

```
{{bindAttr value="ticket.t_date"}}
```

I have a helper function as follow

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('date', function(unixDate){ return unixToDate(unixDate); });
```

I need to use this function inside bindAttr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling a helper inside `bind-attr` is not possible, but you could do it in another way, define a computed property on your model class that makes use of your date formatting helper function as a normal function call:

```
App.Ticket = DS.Model.extend({
  t_date: DS.attr('string'),
  formattedDate: function () {
    return unixToDate(this.get('t_date'));
  }.property('t_date')
});
```

and then use the `formattedDate` in your `bind-attr`:

```
{{#each ticket in model}}
  <input type="text" {{bindAttr value="ticket.formattedDate"}}></input>
{{/each}}
```

See here for a demo of what I mean: http://jsbin.com/UfiSote/5/edit

### Update in response to your comment

Yes it's possible, you then rather need to bind to your `ticket` property:

```
App.MyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  ticket: null,
  formattedDate: function () {
    return unixToDate(this.get('ticket.t_date'));
  }.property('ticket')
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is i have set the json in a property inside my controller. Like controller.set('ticket', json); Is it possible to still use a computed property inside my ticket like you showed.